# Out of range decimal type Mysql?

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to store int and floating values numbers in field.

I use this type for field: `decimal(5,4)`.

When I tried to store number `10` I got an error: `Out of range decimal`.

Why, if `decimal(5,4)` allows 5 position before dot and 4 positions after?

Comment: (5,4) means it has to allow for 4 digits of precision after the decimal. meaning only one position to the left of the decimal can exist.  Therefore it can only be 0-9. which excludes 10+.

Comment: But on to the other issue.  FLOATING point and DECIMAL are not the same thing.  FLOAT, Decimal, Int are all different data types. Float handles really large numbers or really small numbers by giving up exactness of the number for performance.  Who cares if you're off by a few thousand miles if you're talking about light years.  So Storing both types in the same columns seems bad to begin with.  But if you're talking about currency, then using float would be bad as it loses exactness and you'll get errors in your totals over time.

Comment: So I'm worried about mixing int and floating numbers in the same column; which happens to be decimal...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the decimal(x, y) format, the x stands for the total number of digits, and y for the number of digits after the decimal place (. or ,). If assuming you want to store numbers up to 4 digits long (1000) with a precision of 2 (0.01) you'd need to use decimal(6, 2).

Comment: How do you calculate this? `store numbers up to 4 digits long (1000) with a precision of 2` why not this? `decimal(1000, 2)`

Comment: Basically the first parameter is the total number of digits you want (including the ones after the dot) and the 2nd parameter is the number of digits after the dot.

Comment: You need to count the number of digits/characters (1000.00 is 4 characters before the decimal point: 1, 0, 0, 0; then there's 2 characters after the decimal point: 0, 0. Basically whether you want to represent 9999.99 or 1000.00 you still want to use decimal(6, 2)

Comment: Key phrase is `total number of digits`. Thank you now it is clear

Comment: Why are you sure that product can not cost more then decimal(6,2)? Not more then 999999 $?

Comment: If you're calculating a product between 2 numbers, the result will most likely be bigger (and need more space) than the 2 numbers.

Answer (score 4):

You are misunderstanding.  `decimal(5, 4)` has 5 total digits of precision with 4 digits of scale after the decimal place.  Hence, one is before.

You seem to want `decimal(9, 4)`.

Comment: So, based your answer I could not set more then 10? How to be if it is product price?

Comment: You seem to want `decimal(9, 4)`.

Comment: I still dont understand, `5 digits of precision with 4 after the decimal place`

Comment: @OPV . . . `12345`, `1234.5`, `123.45`, `12.345`, `1.2345`, and `0.12345` all have five digits of precision.

Comment: Its have differ precision after dot

Comment: @OPV . . . "Precision is the number of digits in a number. Scale is the number of digits to the right of the decimal point in a number. " (from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/precision-scale-and-length-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017).  I just happened to use the Microsoft documentation, but all databases have the same definitions.

Comment: Okay I have: `decimal(5,4)` it means 00000 totally digits, and 4 is precision. It means 0.0000, so therefore 10 gives me error, yes?